# transactionscope / linq to sql / multiple data contexts

Tags: linq-to-sql, transactionscope

I need some clarification. When we have a transaction scope, does the transaction works across operations done on multiple datacontexts or we are supposed to do db operations only in a single datacontext within the transaction scope.

thanks
xoxo

Answer (score 0):

Transactions can work across datacontexts, but only with the help of [Distributed Transaction Coordinator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759136%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). (It needs to be enabled on every machine that will run your product.)

P.S. In fact it's the connection that matters, not the datacontext itself, but usually theres a 1:1 relation for DC to Connection...